# Failed to load ng-model of dropdown list in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have `items` as my json object which contains some data which i want to show on dropdown list.

But still it is showing my dropdown list as blank.

Here i am using ng-repeat.

[I have listed my code here.](http://jsfiddle.net/baRb5/137/)

HTML :

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">   
    <div ng-repeat="item in items">
        <select ng-model="item.shareToOption" ng-options="c.value for c in shareToOptions"></select>
    </div> 
<div>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

function Ctrl($scope) {
        $scope.items = [
            {
            "shareToOption" : {id:1,value:"AA1"}
            },
            {
            "shareToOption" : {id:2,value:"AA2"},
            },
            {
            "shareToOption" : {id:3,value:"AA3"},
            },
            {
            "shareToOption" : {id:4,value:"AA4"}
            }
        ];

        $scope.shareToOptions = [
            {id:1,value:"AA1"},
            {id:2,value:"AA2"},
            {id:3,value:"AA3"},
            {id:4,value:"AA4"},
            {id:4,value:"AA5"},
            {id:4,value:"AA6"},
            {id:4,value:"AA7"}
        ];
}
```

Comment: Please include the relevant parts of your code in your question.

Comment: The dropdown isn't blank. Please check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the new `track by` expression for `ng-options`. Something like this:

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">   
    <div ng-repeat="item in items">
        <select 
          ng-model="item.shareToOption" 
          ng-options="c.value for c in shareToOptions track by c.id"
        ></select>
    </div> 
<div>
```

Make sure that you're using Angular 1.2.